# SharePoint 2013 Online - Add Attachment : Client Object model

Tags: sharepoint, attachment

Creating a SP 2013 Online app using CSOM. I m creating a custom ASPX page in SP designer, and to insert and update item to a SharePoint list. Earlier the List input form was developed InfoPath 2013, where file Attachment control was used. Since the code is not rewritten using ClientContext, can someone tell me how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to Check out the SharePoint Stackexchange for SharePoint specific questions.

```
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("listtitle");
ListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);
var attachment = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
attachment.FileName = "fileName";
attachment.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("streamFile"));
Attachment att = item.AttachmentFiles.Add(attachment);                                        
context.Load(att);                                     
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144814/how-to-attach-files-to-list-item-using-client-object-model

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I need to have a client side (jquery implementation here, since i m using Client context to read and write items to the list. I m able to save all the fields to the list. I need to have the full code (HTML and jquery)

Comment: https://blogs.ibs.com/2016/06/07/adding-attachments-to-a-list-item-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Sure, this looks good Tom. I will implement this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tom, your suggested link works. But i need to upload multiple files and at the same time, when i view the custom page, i need to view the uploaded file(s). Do you have the code snippet for the same?